# Snakemake with unknown names of multiple outputs from seaborn plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, seaborn, snakemake

I am working snakemake and using seaborn in python.
I have come to a point in the pipeline where snakemake gives missing output.

Pseudocode for snakemake would look a bit like this:

```
WC1 = Wildcard1
WC2 = Wildcard2

rule all:
expand("/path/to/outputs{wc1}_{wc2}.png", wc1=WC1, wc2=WC2)

checkpoint seaborn:
    input:
        "/OtherPath/to/file1.csv"
        "/AnotherPath/to/file2.tsv"
    output:
        "/path/to/outputs{wc1}_{wc2}.png"
    shell:
        "python SeabornPlot.py"
```

The python script, as somewhat pseudocode, would be like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

CSV1 = pd.read_csv(snakemake.input[O], delimiter=",")
CSV2 = pd.read_csv(snakemake.input[1], delimiter=",")

for column in CSV1:
    g = sns.barplot(x=column, data=CSV2)
    fig = g.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(snakemake.output[0]) 
    plt.clf()
```

This does not work. The python script works outside of snakemake (with the correct path and name for the file). I suspect it has something to do with using "snakemake.output[0]", but what can I use instead?

I am quite sure checkpoint is correct here, instead of rule. But please correct me if I am wrong.

Finally, I know something is missing in rule all. I probably should add a function with a new wildcard for each plot.

But the main problem I have is to get python to output the plots to the correct path.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see any reason why you would want checkpoint here instead of rule. Checkpoints are used when a rule generates an unspecified number of outputs AND you have downstream rules that depend on those unknown outputs. You have neither of these.

Comment: Please, please, include your command and error messages in your questions! It makes it a lot easier for folks to help you, and more likely that they will try. Many contributors will just downvote your question and move on if you dont give enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious error in your Snakefile is the rule all. It should have an input.

```
rule all:
    input: expand("/path/to/outputs{wc1}_{wc2}.png", wc1=WC1, wc2=WC2)
```

There is nothing special about the name `all`. If you do not specify a rule or an output file, snakemake simply uses the first rule as the target. By convention (carried over from the original `make` program), the first rule is called `all`, and it only has dependencies (aka `input:`). It does not usually have its own outputs or action (eg: `script:`).